# Ajax only works once when form submitted

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, forms

I am attempting to create a login widget that utilizes ajax on the user side of Wordpress.  I have created a form, ajax and response. The form only works once during testing (as it stands right now I am just testing for responses to the ajax request).

Here is my code:

Form:

```
<form class="fs-login" autocomplete="off" novalidate method="post">
<div class="uk-child-width-auto">
    <div>
        <div class="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-small uk-card-body">
            <div class="uk-inline uk-width-1-1">
                <span class="uk-form-icon" uk-icon="icon: user"></span>
                <input class="uk-input uk-form-small" name="username" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="uk-inline uk-width-1-1">
                <span class="uk-form-icon" uk-icon="icon: lock"></span>
                <input class="uk-input uk-form-small" name="password" type="password">
            </div>
            <button id="fs-login-button" type="submit" class="uk-button uk-button-small uk-width-1-1">Login</button>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-text-small uk-text-center">
            Not registered? <br/><a href="#">Create an account</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
'use strict';

$('.fs-login').on('click', '#fs-login-button', function (){

    var username = $("input[name=username]").val();
    var password = $("input[name=password]").val();

    // if(username.length > 0) {

        $.ajax({

            method: "POST",

            url: ajaxurl,

            data: { 

                'action'        : 'ajaxlogin',

                'username'      : username,

                'password'      : password

            },

            success: function(data){

                if (data.success == true){

                    alert('pass');

                } else {

                    alert('fail');

                }

            }

        });

    // } else {

    //  alert('You have to enter your username');

    // }

});
```

});

Here is my function:

```
public function ajax_login(){

    $data = array( 'success'=>true );

    wp_send_json( $data );

    wp_die();

}
```

Yes I have the following codes added to my files:

```
wp_localize_script( $this->plugin_name, 'ajaxurl', admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) );
```

In addition to :

```
$this->loader->add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajaxlogin', $plugin_public, 'ajax_login' );
$this->loader->add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin', $plugin_public, 'ajax_login' );
```

As I stated, the ajax functions fine the first time I run it. I get the jQuery alert popup.  The second time that I run the program, there is no popup and the script appears to post and load the a new page with no functions being parsed.

Any help is always appreciated.

Mike

Comment: It should be posting to the server and reloading every time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By just looking at it I guess you can do two things:

1. return false on submit handler for example:

`<form onsubmit="return false;" ...`

2. Maybe you also have to extend your clickhandler like:

`... '#fs-login-button', function (e){ e.preventDefault()`

To achieve prevent submitting the form non-ajax, google it you have to do it

Comment: I tried option 2 before, but I wrote it as: "function (event) { event.preventDefault()" This did not work for me.  Writing it your way, it is now working.